# New app not available in list for "insights for your website"

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-insights

I created a new app last week with the purpose of using Facebook insights for our website, but it is not available in the list to make the connection with. Do I need to do anything to make the app selectable?

For any of you people who think this question is not technical and shouldn't be here, I was directed here from Facebook bugs because it's not a bug.

Comment: You mean you search for it and it dosen't appear?

Comment: it's not a search, it's a drop-down of available apps at facebook.com/insights

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue but after a bit of experimenting I found that it does not affect the ability for you to claim a domain and associate it with an app.

What the drop down list does is generate the code snippet shown below. I'm guessing this was useful when you was able to link it to a page_id (you can no longer do this). As long as you have put the correct meta tag (such as that below, replacing `%%app_id%%` with the `app_id` given by the [Facebook App Center](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)) you are free to ignore what account is shown in the drop down.

```
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='%%app_id%%'/>
```

Once you have linked the account you can go back to the [Facebook App Center](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and set permission on the account.

> **Tip**: While you can only give other verified developers *Manager* access to the app you can add any friend or email address to the *insights* level of access which is all which they need.

Comment: Chris - this was helpful, but I think there's still a piece missing.  I'm trying to do the same thing Patrick was trying to do, and maybe we're missing a step in the app creation process or something - because it appears that being able to select the app in the drop-down (instead of selecting myself) is critical to getting Insights to test the link between the app and the root webpage of the site; so the fact that the app is not listed is what appears to be the hurdle right now.  Any thoughts on the app setup required?  There doesn't seem to be a clear way to specify the domain under setup...

Comment: I think this might be the solution Matt. Go to the [Developer Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and go to edit the settings of the relevent app. Under `Select how your app integrates with Facebook` you need to tick `Website with Facebook Login` and fill out the URL. If I remember rightly you will also need to fill out the `App Domains`. Let me know and I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional instructions, Chris - they make sense and I can see why they'd be necessary.  I've completed both steps you noted; upon saving the app with the updated settings, I'm told to "wait a few minutes" while the information propagates.  At this point it's been about a half hour and there's still no option to pick the app in the drop-down for website insights, so I'm afraid I might still be missing something!  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You don't have to wait for it to show, just put the URL in and click `Get Insights`. FB just uses the dropdown to generate the recommended meta tag (which seems broken)

Comment: Hmm.  Well I ended up more or less tricking it I think - because it was refusing to link it if I only put an fb:app_id on the root page. Sorry I didn't capture the error message it was giving me. So I "gave up" and added my fb:admins id in to the root page, linked it that way, and then took my fb:admins id off.  After that, trying to link it - even though the app still doesn't show in the drop-down - it didn't complain and finally gave me access.  So thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case here.  But I **do know** that there is a threshold to see insights with regard to pages.

[As detailed here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) in the FAQ's -

> Is there a minimum number of users to see Insights for Pages? Yes. For
>   user privacy reasons, Insights are only provided to Pages with greater
>   than 30 users who like that Page.

Perhaps there is a limit for domain insights too.  You should allow some time and some traffic pass before the insights start being able to give feedback...

Comment: The *application* is not listed. Even if there is no data available insights should default to show 0 visits.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I tried to debug my site here [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)
which is the official debugger you can input URL, Access Token, or Open Graph Action ID.

It works for me.